# How to make the Firebase app preview page open the app?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

**If the universal links are enabled on the device, dynamic link opens an app directly successfully, but if not link opens app preview page in safari and after clicking the open button App Store page is being opened**

**How can I make the open button open the app, not the App Store**

In the Firebase console, I had specified Bundle Id and Team Id

In the iOS app I had specified the associated domain:

> applinks:my.url.prefix

URL Type with URL Schemes = my.bundle.id, Role = Editor, identifier = auth2

apple-app-site-association file contains the app's data

I construct a dynamic link using REST, here is my request body:

```
{
    "dynamicLinkInfo": {
        "domainUriPrefix": my.url.prefix,
        "link": mylink, 
        "iosInfo": {
            "iosBundleId": my.bundle.id, 
            "iosAppStoreId": appstroreid
        }, 
        "navigationInfo": {
            "enableForcedRedirect": false
        }
    }, 
    "suffix": {
         "option": "UNGUESSABLE"
    }
}
```

The response doesn't have any warnings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned up that it is an iOS bug, sometimes something happening with the apple-app-site-association file and deep won't work
My recommendation to not have an important feature to depend on the deep-link